# Distribution List is empty even after adding the necessary details

Tags: 2013, outbound-email, audience-manager

I am unable to add contacts to my Dynamic Distribution List in Tridion 2013:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the filter details you used to create this distribution list ?